# Hide application task from taskbar but keep window visible in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, 64-bit, taskbar

I want to hide a certain application (in this case Chrome) from the taskbar in Windows 7 64-bit **but keep the window visible** (the window is running permanently visible on a 2nd monitor and I don't want to be bothered by the taskbar icon all the time.).

Anyone did manage to do this somehow?

This is not a duplicate. Please read carefully. The mentioned duplicate topic does not solve the issue (**keeping the window still visible**). That is why I asked this question, again.

Comment: Hopefully, this cannot be acheived

Comment: Isn't this a valid requirement?